# Tomcat7 in eclipse as WTP project not starting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp

I have a WTP project in eclipse that is using Tomcat7 as server, everything is fine - when I start the server, there are no errors in the logs but tomcat is not coming up - hitting localhost:8080 shows me 404 page, I have checked the ports conflicts as well, below are the logs when tomcat starts.

```
    Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Users\ashishs\Downloads
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SK' did not find a matching property.
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 517 ms
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 10 11:07:37 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion <clinit>
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.0.6.RELEASE
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.0.6.RELEASE
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 1900]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-mvc.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-beans.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/database.properties]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/yelp.properties]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:38 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bc1fb9: defining beans [org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,authenticationSuccessHandler,userDAO,userDetailsService,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,passwordEncoder,slingDataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dashboardController,loginController,staticContentController,userController,yelpController,campaignDAOHibernateImpl,userHibernateDAOImpl,campaignManagerImpl,encryptionManagerImpl,userManagerImpl,yelpManagerImpl,propertyConfigurer,jspViewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver#0,jsonNames,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:39 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@158497c] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/view.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@1b4cd65: startup date [Tue Apr 10 11:07:40 IST 2012]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9d22fc: defining beans [jsonNames]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bc1fb9
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/dashboard.htm] onto handler 'dashboardController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/addSlingwallet.htm] onto handler 'dashboardController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.htm] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/static-about-us.htm] onto handler 'staticContentController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/signup-user.htm] onto handler 'userController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/signup-page.htm] onto handler 'userController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/testYelp.htm] onto handler 'yelpController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/searchyelp.htm] onto handler 'yelpController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:40 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3731 ms
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'myappConsumer'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'myappConsumer': initialization started
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'myappConsumer-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 10 11:07:41 IST 2012]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-mvc.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-beans.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1031310: defining beans [jspViewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver#0,jsonNames,dashboardController,loginController,staticContentController,userController,yelpController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bc1fb9
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/view.xml]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@16b69d7: startup date [Tue Apr 10 11:07:41 IST 2012]; parent: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'myappConsumer-servlet'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@25b64d: defining beans [jsonNames]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1031310
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/dashboard.htm] onto handler 'dashboardController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/addSlingwallet.htm] onto handler 'dashboardController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.htm] onto handler 'loginController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/static-about-us.htm] onto handler 'staticContentController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/signup-user.htm] onto handler 'userController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/signup-page.htm] onto handler 'userController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/testYelp.htm] onto handler 'yelpController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/searchyelp.htm] onto handler 'yelpController'
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'myappConsumer': initialization completed in 133 ms
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Apr 10, 2012 11:07:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4398 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Eclipse when you deploy a web project is not mapped to the root path, but with a context path that has the same name of the project.

That is, if you project name is "WebTest" try to hit

```
http://localhost:8080/WebTest
```

However to be sure verify in your server.xml configuration file that:

- Tomcat port is 8080
- Your context name is mapped with the project name

Comment: yes..dash1e you are right but the issue was something else in my code which I realized now..
Actually in file org.eclipse.wst.common.component my wb-module's deploy-name was different from context-root value. I was using wb-module's deploy-name as my context but actually it should be the context-root value.